# C++11 variable argument alignment

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, variadic-functions

This is the interface I am trying to achieve:

```
 Statement  select("SELECT * FROM People WHERE ID > ? AND ID < ?");
 select.execute(1462, 1477, [](int ID, std::string const& person, double item1, float item2){
     std::cout << "Got Row:" 
               << ID     << ", " 
               << person << ", " 
               << item1  << ", " 
               << item2  << "\n";
 });
```

Where the '?' in the select string are matched against the variable argument list `1462, 1477` at runtime.

This is the class definition:

```
class Statement
{
    public:
        Statement(std::string const&);

        template<class Action, class ...Args>
        void execute(Args... param, Action action);
};
```

Unfortunately this generates an error:

> test.cpp:133:12: error: no matching member function for call to 'execute'
>   select.execute(1462, 1477, [](int ID, std::string const& person, double item1, float item2){
>   ~~~~~^~~~~~~
>
> test.cpp:86:14: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Action'
>   void execute(Args... param, Action action)
>   ~~~^~~~~~~
>
> 1 error generated.

But if I change the function definition slightly (below) it compiles fine.

```
class Statement
{
    public:
        Statement(std::string const&);

        template<class Action, class ...Args>
        void execute(Action action, Args... param);
                  // ^^^^^^^ Move action to the front.
};
// Also changed the call by moving the lambda to the first argument.
```

I know its some syntactic sugar where the variable argument list goes, but I would like to put the variable argument list first. Are there any tricks I can use to help the compiler deduce the var arg list correctly?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible the way you'd like it, but what about changing the API slightly so that execute returns a callable which takes your lambda? Looks almost the same:
`select.execute(1462, 1477)([](int ID...){...})`

Comment: @lethal-guitar: Yep I have done that already (but I called it bind). But that leaves the possibility for the user of the code to capture bound statements (which I don't want). `auto& bind  = select.bind(1462, 1477);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided that I would use `std::tuple` as a parameter and hide the parameter expansion:

#### Usage is now:

```
select.execute(
    Bind(1462, 1477), 
    [](int ID, std::string const& person, double item1, float item2){
        std::cout << "Got Row:" 
                  << ID     << ", " 
                  << person << ", " 
                  << item1  << ", " 
                  << item2  << "\n";
});
```

Then I defined:

```
template<typename ...Args>
inline std::tuple<Args...> Bind(Args... args) { return std::tuple<Args...>(args...);}
```

The class is redefined like this:

```
class Statement
{
    public:
        Statement(std::string const&);

        template<class Action, class ...Args>
        void execute(std::tuple<Args...> const& param, Action action);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit ugly, but you could use tuples:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template<int... Is>
struct integer_sequence {};
template<int N, int... Is>
struct make_integer_sequence : make_integer_sequence<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template<int... Is>
struct make_integer_sequence<0, Is...> : integer_sequence<Is...> {};

class Statement
{
    private:
        std::string foo;

    public:
        Statement(std::string const& p)
            : foo(p)
        {}

        template<class ...Args>
        void execute(Args... param)
        {
            execute_impl(make_integer_sequence<sizeof...(Args)-1>{}, param...);
        }

        template<int... Is, class... Args>
        void execute_impl(integer_sequence<Is...>, Args... param)
        {
            std::get<sizeof...(Args)-1>(std::tie(param...))
                (std::get<Is>(std::tie(param...))..., foo);
        }
};
```

Usage example:

```
int main()
{
    Statement s("world");
    s.execute("hello", ", ",
              [](std::string const& p1, std::string const& p2,
                 std::string const& p3)
              { std::cout << p1 << p2 << p3; });
    std::cout << "\nEND\n";
}
```

---

Here's an alternative solution, a bit less ugly but more verbose:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template<class Tuple, class...>
struct pop_back;

template<class T, class... Ts, class... Us>
struct pop_back<std::tuple<T, Ts...>, Us...>
    : pop_back<std::tuple<Ts...>, Us..., T>
{};

template<class T, class... Us>
struct pop_back<std::tuple<T>, Us...>
{
    using type = std::tuple<Us...>;
};

class Statement
{
    private:
        std::string foo;

    public:
        Statement(std::string const& p)
            : foo(p)
        {}

        template<class ...Args>
        void execute(Args... param)
        {
            helper<typename pop_back<std::tuple<Args...>>::type>
                ::execute(param..., foo);
        }

        template<class T>
        struct helper;

        template<class... Args>
        struct helper< std::tuple<Args...> >
        {
            template<class Action>
            static void execute(Args... param, Action action, std::string foo)
            {
                action(param..., foo);
            }
        };
};
```

---

Here's a short `is_callable` trait that allows a `static_assert` for nicer error messages:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
struct is_callable
{
    template<class F1>
    static auto test(int)
        -> decltype( std::declval<F1>() (std::declval<Args>()...),
                     std::true_type{} );

    template<class F1>
    static std::false_type test(...);

    constexpr static auto value = decltype(test<F>(0))::value;
};
```

For example:

```
template<int... Is, class... Args>
void execute_impl(integer_sequence<Is...>, Args... param)
{
    auto& action = std::get<sizeof...(Args)-1>(std::tie(param...));
    auto param_tuple = std::tie(param...);

    static_assert(is_callable<decltype(action),
                              typename std::tuple_element<Is,
                                              decltype(param_tuple)>::type...,
                              decltype(foo)>::value,
                  "The action is not callable with those argument types.");

    action(std::get<Is>(param_tuple)..., foo);
}
```

Comment: My first try was to put the parameter pack in a non-deduced context: `template<class... Args, class Action> void execute_impl(typename identity<Args>::type..., Action);` and then explicitly supplying the `Args...` where the last parameter has been popped. But for some reason, this doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Parameter pack cannot be deduced if they are not at the end of a function call.

Quote from the standard, `14.8.2.1 Deducing template arguments from a function call`

Rules for the parameter pack at the end :

> For a function parameter pack that occurs at the end of the
>   parameter-declaration-list, the type A of each remaining argument of
>   the call is compared with the type P of the declarator-id of the
>   function parameter pack. Each comparison deduces template arguments
>   for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by
>   the function parameter pack.

Other else :

> For a function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the
>   parameter-declaration-list, the type of the parameter pack is a
>   non-deduced context.

Comment: Yep. I figured out the compiler will not let me do it. I want to try and come up with an alternative that gives me the interface I want so that users of my class can intuitively use it (but can make a mess with the class).

Comment: The dip solution is working then, but it hides the logic of the last arguments and obscure the compiler error message if something is wrong. You better have to write a nice API documentation if you rely of things like that.